# How to take full size page snapshot with Selenium on java?

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot, snapshot

How to take full size page snapshot with Selenium on java? My page resolution more than screen resolution. When i try to set browser resolution more than the screen resolution, browser opening in full size of screen resolution. Preferably without reference to page.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use the headless driver [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). This works fine for me, but I didn't tried with FirefoxDriver. You haven't shown what you tried so far, so I don't know which driver you use and if you already tried this.

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Now you can save the screenshot file with simple IO. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver) is helpful, too.

Comment: I know about phantomjs, i'm using it. But I need to use another browsers, like a chrome, firefox...